# LinearRegressionWithSGD.train "error: type mismatch "

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use Spark with Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScaler
val scaler = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = true).fit(
  labeledPoints.rdd.map(x => x.features)
)

val scaledLabledPoints = labeledPoints.map{ x =>
  LabeledPoint(x.label, scaler.transform(x.features))
} 

import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
val numIter = 20
scaledLabledPoints.cache

val linearRegressionModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(scaledLabledPoints, numIter)
```

This error happen on the last line:

```
<console>:64: error: type mismatch;
 found   :  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
   val linearRegressionModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(scaledLabledPoints, numIter)
                                                             ^
```

How can this error be solved and why does it occur?

Comment: You are trying to use a dataframe but `LinearRegressionWithSGD` expects a RDD as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are working with DataFrames and Datasets but also using the old RDD API for Spark MLlib. You should use the ML API : org.apache.spark.ml library (instead of mllib)

If you still wanna use the MLlib API, you might try this :

```
val linearRegressionModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(scaledLabledPoints.rdd, numIter)
```